# Coefficients of a rational function that depend meromorphically on a parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, modular-forms

Let $D \equiv 1, 2 \, (\textrm{mod }4)$ be a positive, squarefree integer. Let
\begin{align}
r_D(n) = \{(x, y) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \mid x^2 + Dy^2 = n\}
\end{align}
for any positive integer $n$. Consider the Dirichlet series
\begin{align}
R_D(s) :=
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{r_D(n)}{n^s} = \sum_{\substack{(x, y) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \\ (x, y) \neq (0, 0)}} \frac{1}{|x + y\sqrt{-D}|^2} =
D^{-s/2}
\sum_{\substack{(x, y) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \\ (x, y) \neq (0, 0)}}
\frac{(\sqrt{D})^s}{|x + y\sqrt{-D}|^2}.
\end{align}
Therefore the values taken by $R_D(s)$ are (almost) special values of the Eisenstein series
\begin{align}
\tilde{G}_{2s}(\tau) = \sum_{\substack{(x, y) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \\ (x, y) \neq (0, 0)}}
\frac{\textrm{Im}(\tau)^s}{|x + y\tau|^{2s}}
\end{align}
obtained by taking $\tau = \sqrt{-D}$. The function $\tilde{G}_{2s}(\tau)$ is weakly modular of weight zero with a simple pole at $\infty$. Any such function is a rational function in $j$, where
\begin{align}
j(\tau) = \frac{1}{q} + 744 + 196884q + \dots
\end{align}
is the $j$-invariant function. Hence we can write
\begin{align}
R_D(s) = D^{-s/2}P_s\Big(j\big(\sqrt{-D}\big)\Big)
\end{align}
where $P_s(z) \in \mathbf{C}(z)$ are some rational functions, depending on $s$. I want to know what can be said about these $P_s$ functions as $s$ varies.

To motivate: if the coefficients of $P_s$ are rational functions of $s$, I immediately find that the sums
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{r_D(n)}{n^k}
\end{align}
are algebraic numbers for all rational $k$ where the sum converges.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user297024 , but why can't I take $\tau$ to be complex? Perhaps this is because $\textrm{Im}(\tau)$ isn't holomorphic in $\tau$?

Comment: @user297024 Thanks for the comments. I understand the issue now. Would you be able to leave an answer summarising your comments so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the function $\tilde{G}_{2s}(\tau)$ only takes real values, so it cannot be meromorphic unless it is constant (it would be constant on an open set by Cauchy-Riemann, hence constant everywhere by identity theorem). Although it is weakly modular of weight zero, we cannot say that it is a rational function in $j$, i.e., it is not meromorphic so it is not in the function field of the curve $X(1)$.